# Is it possible to to encrypt multiple messages with multiple keys and get only one cipher?

Tags: encryption

I want to have cipher which when people decrypt it with their own key, get different meaningful messages. Is this possible at all?

Comment: The search term you need is "deniable encryption" - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deniable_encryption for some examples.

Comment: Is the question in the title related in any way to the question in the body?

Comment: @techraf: Yes, see Matthew's link.

Comment: @Armita: It has been answered [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/13049) by fgrieu. One simple example would be to use the XOR cipher, e.g. try do decipher `random` (ASCII) using the key `0x2140c08060e` (hex), and the key `0x1040d160a19` (hex). You can use [xor.pw](http://xor.pw) to do it online.

Comment: @Yuriko The questions still seem different to me. Can you explain?

Comment: @techraf: The title asks whether it is possible to have several `(plaintxt_1, key_1)`, `(plaintxt_2, key_2)`, …, `(plaintxt_n, key_n)` that all produce the same `ciphertxt`. The cipher used is not specified. The content asks whether it is possible to create that `ciphertxt`. (So, when someone decrypt it using `key_i`, they get `plaintxt_i`.)

Comment: I don't know the term, but it sounds like the structure for the title would be `with A, can I get B` and for the content would be `can I get B, such as A`. I might be wrong, but the logic seems correct to me. In the case it's not, a simple explanation about what it is not correct would be constructive. :-)

Comment: If this was possible, that would be an **awesome** compression algorithm. Take the first 128-bit block of a terabyte-sized file, and encrypt it. That's the compression part. To decompress, decrypt the block using 62.5 billion different keys, magically restoring the complete  file.

Comment: @Damon: Obviously, no; how will you store those keys? Why 62.5 billions?

Comment: @Yuriko Yes, I interpret it in the same way. Yet I can't see it being equivalent to the question in the body.

Comment: Do you want to hide the fact that the ciphertext might contain other messages? If not, then take any number of plaintexts, add an indicator, encode each plaintext+indicator with different key, concatenate ciphertexts with or without an interleave. Distribute keys to different parties. Give them a decryption mechanism which will do a trial-and-error for each offset until indicator is found. Proceed with decryption for the discovered offset. Ignore data at other offsets. Or explicitly attach an offset to a key.

Answer (score 1):

In theory yes. In practice no.

You could use one-time pad cipher like

```
a \xor k = b and c \xor k' = b
```

But this reverses the role of the key and message. `b` becomes the key and `k`/`k'` the cipher text. In fact you could change the XOR function to any other function, it would need the same properties and therefore have the same weaknesses.

Comment: The bits in the plaintext of `a` that are equal to `c` would result in identical bits in `k` and `k'`. So the holder of `k` would directly be able to see (part of) `k'` and vice versa. I would not even call that "broken".

Comment: My point is, technically, in a one time pad, if you get the cipher text, you can create a key that gives you a chosen message (of the same size). So yes you can have two plain texts, with different key, giving the same cipher text.

Comment: I think we agree that although the scheme is possible that the resulting keys are related and therefore do not offer (sufficient) security?

Comment: I don't think it's a security problem per se. But rather that the information is carried by the key instead of the cipher in this case. It is like we chose `b` as the key and `k` or `k'` are the cipher texts of `a` and `c`.